# ubuntu boot cd unable to burn on disk utility

Tags: cd, burning

I have downloaded the Iso file of ubuntu and I am trying to burn a boot cd from disk utility the burn goes all the way to the end and right before ejecting cd it read

```
Burn failed
2012-08-19 20:13:27 -0700:  The disc drive didn’t respond properly and can’t recover or retry.
2012-08-19 20:13:28 -0700:      Additional information can be found in the ~/Library/Logs/DiscRecording.log log file.
2012-08-19 20:13:28 -0700: Unable to burn “ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso.” (The disc drive didn’t respond properly and can’t recover or retry.)
```

can anyone explain this do I have a bad superdrive or am I doing something else wrong I am on a mid 2007 macbook any support would be nice thank you.

Comment: Have you tried different media?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a bad iso file. Try re-downloading the iso again. To ensure that your iso downloaded correctly, check `md5sum` output from the Disk utility by selecting the iso file in Disk Utility, then go to the "Images" menu and select Checksum > MD5. Be sure to choose "MD5" and NOT "MD5 image checksum" or "CRC-32 image checksum", as they are not the same and will give you different results. Compare the result to the output shown below:

```
9fcc322536575dda5879c279f0b142d7 *ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso
bcee4c03b704a9b62988505b7d8f3069 *ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso
128f0c16f4734c420b0185a492d92e52 *ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso
d791352694374f1c478779f7f4447a3f *ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
f2e921788d35bbdf0336d05d228136eb *ubuntu-12.04-server-amd64.iso
32184a83c8b5e6031e1264e5c499bc03 *ubuntu-12.04-server-i386.iso
d4aa1eb1131bacd46317dad1afc59ff6 *ubuntu-12.04-wubi-amd64.tar.xz
33452f884d1017aadde0ec468b83264c *ubuntu-12.04-wubi-i386.tar.xz
9813c75c0ef631942b4c9f989588ab85 *wubi.exe
```